# Do females retain oogonia after puberty?

Tags: reproductive-biology

Oogonia are the precursors of oocytes in females present during embryonic development. I was wondering whether these stem cells are still present in the ovaria at puberty?

Comment: I slightly modified your question for the sake of clarity. Please feel free to roll back if the question edits are not to your liking. Welcome to Biology and +1 for your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Developmental Biology, 6<sup>th</sup> edition](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK10008/) I learned the following:

In humans, the oogonia divide to form a limited number of egg precursor cells. In the human embryo, the thousand or so **oogonia** divide rapidly from the second to the seventh month of gestation to form roughly 7 million **germ cells**. After the seventh month of embryonic development the number of germ cells drops and most oogonia die during this period, while the remaining oogonia enter the first meiotic division. These latter cells, called the **primary oocytes**, progress through the first meiotic prophase until the diplotene stage, at which point they are maintained until puberty.

Hence, at puberty the cells from the lineage of oogonia are called primary oocytes. So from a terminological perspective, you are correct that **no oogonia are thought to be left at puberty**.